# Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid BigNumber bignumber/5.5.0)web3 reactjs solidity

Tags: solidity

> Error Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=["7"], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)

I'm trying to use a form to submit the data, but every time I try to run the code it throws an error.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
  uint storedData;

  function set(uint256 x) public {
    storedData = x;
  }

  function get() public view returns (uint) {
    return storedData;
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the x value? From the error message it seems you are sending an array `["7"]` and it is expecting an uint256 `"7"`.

Comment: @Sky `uint` and `uint256` are exactly the same. If you compile a contract that uses `uint` and examine the resulting ABI the compiler replaces them by `uint256`.

Answer (score 0):

I copy-pasted you code on REMIX IDE (It's an online Solidity compiler).
And your code runs fine, no error at all.

Where are you trying to run your code?

Comment: trying to connect from React js , i did truffle unbox react. It works fine with string in the back ground but when it comes to uint , there is the above error . Thanku

Comment: What di I need to do to reproduce your error? Please explain in detail